# Adding external HTML file to Drupal

Tags: html, drupal

I have Created a Site using Drupal - Acquia Dev Desktop. Now I wanted to add an HTML file (Data Table) which I coded in a text editor to my Drupal site. Is there any way to do this? I searched all over the internet and I can't find a possible solution for this one. I am new to Drupal, step by step explanation or a link to follow is appreciatable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a basic page in drupal (Content -> Add Content -> Basic Page) and then just simply copy the HTML content you created into the body field. You will probably have to change the text format setting of the field to "Full HTML" to keep all of your formatting.

If the source content you created contains complete HTML for a page, including the <html> and <head> tags, then you should only copy the parts *between* the <body> tag from the source.

Comment: This is my code for database tabel. how should i write it in drupal ? In body section, should i simply copy this code ? Link for my code : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qoqdZj